# why ngIf works in unexpected way (Angular)?

Tags: angular

Why this component returns 'no length' instead of 'length exist'?

This is the code

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  length:number = 1;  
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div *ngIf="length > 0; then length else noLength"></div>
<ng-template #length>length exist</ng-template>
<ng-template #noLength>no length</ng-template>
```

Comment: because you re-define length as template reference. and template reference is an object, and .object> 0 returns false.  so you can rename template reference as hasLength, say.

Comment: @ABOS thanks, yes this seems to be the problem!!